# Sum function not giving right answer

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am using the following code to sum all the numbers in different columns. The formula always gives me wrong answer. Please help! Thanks

```
Sub TOTALVALNEW(colNumber As Integer)

Dim StartOfTheRANGE As Range
Dim EndOfTheRange As Range


Set StartOfTheRANGE = Evaluation.Cells(3, colNumber)

Set EndOfTheRange = StartOfTheRANGE.End(xlDown)

'Evaluation is the name of the sheet.
Evaluation.Cells(3, colNumber).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Application.Sum(StartOfTheRANGE, EndOfTheRange)


End Sub
```

Comment: you forget to mentioned how you suppose function should work

Comment: The procedure TOTALVALNEW takes colNumner as integer and calculates the total and  put it at the end of the selected column of evaluation sheet.

Comment: Total of the range whose starting cell is called "startofhterange" and the ending cell is called "endoftherange"

Comment: I checked.  Set EndOfTheRange = StartOfTheRANGE.End(xlDown) refers to the correct cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA's `Application.Sum` works exactly the same as the worksheet function `SUM()` in a cell formula. It takes an object, or a list of objects. If you specify two objects namely the first and last cells, it will just take the sum of the values of the contents first and last cells only (a 2-term sum), not anything in between. If you want to include all cells between the first cell and last cell inclusive, you need to make make a range object by using the `Range()` function. So changing to this:

```
Evaluation.Cells(3, colNumber).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Application.Sum(Range(StartOfTheRANGE, EndOfTheRange))
```

should work.